# What is tf_static?

Tags: ros, tf-static

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am currently writing my masters thesis. I used a lot of different algorithms like Hector mapping, Gmapping and AMCL.
I am trying to explain those by using the RQT-graphs. In each of those graphs I see the tf_static topic. What is function of this?
[image: image description]

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235458/what-is-tf_static?/) by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-05-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Transforms on the /tf_static topic are assumed to never change and be valid for all timestamps.
http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration#Addition_of_.2BAC8-tf_static_topic

Because tf uses tf2 under the hood, tf::TransformListener will subscribe to both the /tf and /tf_static topics automatically.
http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on 2016-05-30**:
In my launch file I use:

```
<!-- tf transform -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_nav_broadcaster" args="-0.45 0 0 3.1765 0 3.1415 /base_link /laser 100"/>
```

Has this anything to do with /tf_static or is it just the /map_nav_broadcaster node?

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2016-05-30**:
No. The map_nav_broadcaster node is only publishing `/tf`. The only node subscribing to `/tf_static` is slam_gmapping.

The slam_gmapping node is listening for transforms on both the `/tf` and `/tf_static` topics.

**Comment by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on 2016-06-29**:
Is there an easy way to prevent tf::TransformListeer from subscribing to the /tf_static topic? (only for the sake of clarity of the rqt_graph...)

**Comment by [Przemek Dyszczyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39667/przemek-dyszczyk/) on 2019-01-24**:
it is possible to remap in launcher /tf_static to /tf. But I don't know if it is good idea:

`<remap from="tf_static" to="tf" />`

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2019-01-24**:
In Melodic rqt_graph has an option to group the two tf topics into a single group for visualization: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/pull/13